# Split a String into individual words and ignore everything else

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I want to split a string into individual words. If the String is:

```
String s = "Practice makes perfect. you'll only get Perfect by practice. just practice!";
```

I want to store as:

```
String[] str = {"Practice", "makes", "perfect", "youll", "only", "get", "Perfect", "by", "practice", "just", "practice"};
```

If I use `s.split("\\W")` the `you'll` turns into `you ll`. How do I make it `youll`?

Comment: First `s.replace("'", "")`

Comment: Did you mean String[] str = {"Practice", "makes", "perfect", ....} ?

Comment: @ParakramMajumdar Yes that's how I want them and ignore everything else. If the word is you'll it should be youll.

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily done by first removing the ':

```
String[] str = s.replace("'", "").split("\\W+");
```

Also add `+` to your split to avoid empty slots in your array.

Output:

```
[Practice, makes, perfect, youll, only, get, Perfect, by, practice, just, practice]
```

Comment: @RockySingh please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
string.replaceAll("[\\W&&\\S]", "").split("\\s+");
```